# Find images by absolute path in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried:

```
$("img[src='"+imgSrc+"']")
```

but it did not work. imgSrc is an absolute path, but the path in the HTML file is relative. Knowing that I can't modify `imgSrc`, how can I find images by their absolute path?

Comment: Im guessing you are trying to reference pictures that you yourself are not hosting?? Also imgSrc how do you get that value?

Comment: It's for a Google Chrome extension, I only get the path of the image clicked, so I have to find the image with my own code.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: That seems...odd... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is finding the `img` elements and looking at their `src` *property* (rather than attribute; they're different for images with relative paths) to pick out the one(s) you want, e.g.:

```
$("img[src]").each(function() {
    // Here, `this.src` will be the absolute path
    if (this.src === imageSrc) {
        // Do something, and optionally `return false` to break the
        // loop if you're done
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/unojus)

Answer (score -1):

Browsers handles paths different. You can use `$` in your selector to find images ends with `imgSrc` if it solves your problem.

```
$("img[src$='"+imgSrc+"']")
```

Comment: If `imgSrc` is the *absolute* path, there's no chance that the *relative* path in the `src` attribute on the element will end with it .